# error in sending attachment mail in wp_mail using wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using the following code :

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type');
function set_html_content_type() {
return 'text/html';
}
    $headers = 'From: xxxn <info@xxx.co.in>' . "\r\n";

    $subject = 'Your Axxxxrship 2017';

    $msg = 'Dear '.ucfirst($get_s[0]->name)."<br/><br/>
    Thank You for taking intrest in Scholarship 2017. We have recieved Payment from you. Please find the admit card for your Future
    reference. <br/><br/>
    Thanks & Regards<br/>
    xxxxxx
    ";
    $up = __DIR__ . '/menu-pages/admit_card/'.$stid.'.pdf';
    $mail_attachment = array($up);   

wp_mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers,$mail_attachment);
remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type');
```

But I am trying to send the mail. The mail is sent successfully but I didnt recieve any attachment in the mail.

How I can trace that what is the problem. Path of sending file is :

```
/home/xcdx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/schloarship/menu-pages/admit_card/20108.pdf
```

Comment: Did you try `WP_CONTENT_DIR` constant instead `__DIR__`?

Comment: Yep I have tried but not working